# How do I split an iterable dataset into training and test datasets?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have an iterable dataset object with all of my data files. How can I split it into train and validation set. I have seen a few solutions for custom datasets but iterable does not support `len()` operator.
`torch.utils.random_sample()` and `torch.utils.SubsetRandomSample()` don't work.

```
def __init__(self):
    bla bla
def __iter__(self):
    bla bla
    yield batch
```

Comment: How would you go about splitting your dataset if you don't know its length? That's not possible, you have to know the underlying data size, otherwise you simply can't split it.

Comment: I am open to other suggestions, I have to use iterabledataset. I want to make sure I'm not missing anything. Otherwise, I can divide the samples before passing through the dataset and accept an imperfect ratio by calling dataset separately for the two sets.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can just set a goal ratio, and start collecting items into two lists randomly using that ratio. The result won't be perfect, but asymptotically it will keep the ratio.

The example is JavaScript, as it can be run here:

```js
{
  let a = [],
      b = [];
  function addsample(x) {
    if (Math.random() < 0.2) // aims for 20%-80% split
      a.push(x);
    else
      b.push(x);
    return {a, b};
  }
}

for(let i=0;i<20;i++)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(addsample(i)));
```

If you run the snippet a couple times, you will see that the output varies a lot, but even with such a small sample size it's quite visible, that usually there is a suitable split available all the time where `a` really has around 1/4 the size of `b`. Sometimes it even manages to end up exactly 4:16, but many times it will be something else. And there can be "unlucky" runs too, when `a` has more elements than `b` at the end.